# How do i automatically send ebooks to my Kindle?

Tags: applescript, automation

I would like to create an automation, that automatically sends a new file to my kindle email address if i put a new ebook into that folder.

How would a script look like, that i would have to apply to my folder?

Comment: You're looking for a folder action, an extremely complicated one since Amazon provide no interfaces for AppleScript.

Comment: @ShaneHsu As long as the solution consists of just sending an email to the Kindle email adress, no Kindle-specific AppleScript is required.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because it changes the nature of the question and invalidates the already accepted answer. Using DSW is an interesting idea though, so you could ask a new question along the lines of "How can I use DSW to ...".

Comment: ok then the DSW would be an alternative answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Mac You can use automator to set up a folder action for this. I added a filter for mobi files use this folder action directly with my Downloads folder. The Script consists of three actions:

The first action would be this applescript:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set theFile to first item in input
    set theFileAsString to theFile as string
    if theFileAsString ends with "mobi" then
        return theFile
    else
        tell me to quit
    end if
end run
```

Second, you need a "New Mail Message" action with your name@kindle.com email address. Be sure, that the sending mail address is trusted in your kindle settings of your Amazon account.

Third, you would use the "Send Outgoing Messages" action.

Be aware that this script takes only the first mobi file when you drop multiple files at once into your folder.

Comment: cool thanks! maybe you can add, how the "Send Outgoing Messages" must look like too

Comment: "New Mail Message" and "Send Outgoing Messages" are standard Automator actions. There is no further configuration necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it like Simon said

But this is interesting too: [Do Something When - Project](http://www.azarhi.com/Projects/DSW/)

I think that could solve problems like this too.